# Как правильно сделать асинхронные mysql запросы java

Tags: java, mysql, база-данных, запрос, асинхронность

У меня асинхронные запросы к mysql базе на java, но может быть такое, что второй запрос выполнится быстрее первого, а уже потом выполнится первый, что приведет к откату данных, как это можно решить без очереди, ведь очередь будет работать очень медленно, а мне нужно записать максимально быстро. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Вам нужно выполнять операции последовательно, иначе будут ошибки. Вы выполняете параллельно и у вас ошибки. Ответ напрашивается сам собой

Comment: Вы точно не путаете асинхронные и параллельные запросы? Уточните вопрос, в частности, каким способом вы делаете асинхронные запросы, стандартно в java есть только синхронные, значит, если у вас действительно асинхронные запросы, то у вас используется сторонняя библиотека. Во-вторых, почему это "если второй запрос выполнится быстрее первого" то будет откат данных? Объясните, что вы имеете ввиду.

Comment: @RomanKonoval под асинхронным запросом я имею ввиду Executors.newCachedThreadPool() `DataBase.executor.submit(() -> { statement.execute("UPDATE test SET test_value = 5 WHERE chat_id = 10"); })`, а под откатом я имею ввиду, например если одновременно начнет выполнятся 2 запроса, то запрос который пришел вторым, может выполнится первым, а уже потом выполнится первый и обновит данные до момента создания второго. Хоть у меня и не было такой ситуации, но я решил перестраховаться. А паралельные/асинхронные запросы мне нужны для максимально быстрого ответа у бота vk

Comment: Если нужно 1. выполнять по очереди в том порядке в котором они пришли 2. но в отдельном потоке, то достаточно сделать чтоб у executor-а был только один поток (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int) с параметром 1). В таком случае запросы всегда будут выполняться в порядке добавления, один выполняется, остальные ждут в очереди.

Comment: @RomanKonoval Спасибо большое, помогли! Если хотите напишите это как ответ, я отмечу как правильное решение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если для запросов есть способ установить порядок (например, номер запроса по порядку получения или время запроса), то можно его сохранять в БД и делать условное обновление:

```
UPDATE test
SET test_value = 5, sequence_number = 6
WHERE sequence_number < 6 and chat_id = 10
```

Тогда более старый запрос попросту ничего не обновит, так как его условие на порядковый номер отфильтрует более новую запись.